# c++ Klocwork error memory is allocated through the call to 'new[]'

Tags: c++, memory, klocwork

Klocwork 2020.1 Build 20.1.0.97

```
// Vertices of simplex
auto v = new double*[n + 1]; // this line give the error
// Average coordinates
auto v_ave = new double[n];
// Reflection coordinates
auto v_ref = new double[n];
// Expansion coordinates
auto v_exp = new double[n];
// Contraction coordinates
auto v_con = new double[n];

 if (v == nullptr || v_ave == nullptr || v_ref == nullptr || v_exp == nullptr || v_con == nullptr)
 {
     status = false;
     goto free_mem;
  }

    // Allocate the columns of the arrays
    for (int idx = 0; idx <= n; idx++)
    {
        v[idx] = new double[n];
        if (v[idx] == nullptr)
        {
           status = false;
           goto free_mem;
        }
    }
```

....
this is how the memory is free

```
free_mem:
    if (v != nullptr)
    {
        // Free memory
        for (int idx = 0; idx <= n; idx++)
        {
            delete[] v[idx];
        }
        delete[] v;
    }

    delete[] v_ave;
    delete[] v_ref;
    delete[] v_con;
    delete[] v_exp;

    return pair<double, bool>(min, status);
```

this is the KW error get
[image]

I don't understand the issue and I can't find any suggestion for the fix.

Comment: For any kind of "dynamic array" the proper solution is almost always `std::vector`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are totally right. but this not my code and I want just to unblock this KW issue.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The check is necessary. `delete[] v[idx];` would be UB if `v` is null.

Comment: Well, using a vector is the "proper" fix really. Unless you just want to mute the error (which is typically possible with static analyzers, but if you do it globally then you might miss places where this error is warranted).

Comment: Your code, as shown, initialises `v` using `new double*[n + 1]`, and does not initialise any elements of `v`.   The deallocation code releases (using `delete[]`)  each element of `v`, and then `v` itself.    So the deallocation does not correspond to the allocation.    Also, when releasing `v`, there is no need to check if `v` (or any of the other pointers) is `nullptr` since, by default, a `new[]` expression throws an exception instead of giving a value of `nullptr`.

Comment: @Peter i'll edit and add the code of the allocation of v[i]

Comment: @Gilad - It does help if you post representative code the FIRST time, while than (as you have) omitting relevant sections of code, and then editing them in when problems are found in the code you have posted.

Comment: @Peter sorry I was sure it wasn't relevant only after you commented I noticed it is really important.

Comment: Your code will throw an exception if any of the `new` expressions fail. This means none of the pointers will ever be `nullptr`, so comparing any of them with `nullptr` achieves nothing. There will also be a memory leak if any `new` expression after the first fails, since the code after label `free_mem` will not be executed *at all* if an exception is thrown. This is why people will recommend using `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` for `v` and `std::vector<double>` for other variables - `std::vector` ensures dynamically allocated memory it manages is released even if an exception is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > memory is allocated through the call to 'new[]'
>
> I can't find any suggestion for the fix.

To fix the error "memory is allocated through the call to new[]" is to not allocate memory through new[]. Simplest solution is to use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @eeroika I can't change the type of v.

Comment: You can initialise `v` to point to an array within a vector as a workaround. It's a bit complicated, but there's not much that can be one with the odd combination of restrictions that you have.

Comment: vector->data() you mean? the problem is that later the code uses v in many more places and pass in to other functions. so in order to change the type now i need to spend 2 days. which I don't have now.

Comment: @Gilad Yes, `data` would give you that pointer. I don't see how `v` being used would be a problem. Regardless, this is how the error can be fixed. Whether it takes too long for you to fix doesn't change that.

Comment: `std::vector<double*> real_v(n + 1); auto v = real_v.data();`? You still have `v` the same as before and with the same type. It's not a perfect solution since what the code really should have is `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`.